# (Float) Typecast in C

Tags: c, casting, typecast-operator

I am currently learning C and typecasts and it is suggesting that if I want to convert an int to a float I should precede the variable with `(float)` to do this.

However, when I don't use the typecast, the answer still comes out correct, even though I am mixing the ints and floats.

Can someone explain why/when I would need to use the typecast `(float)` in particular?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int A, B, E;
    float C, D;

    A = 2;
    B = 1;
    C = 12.5;

    D = C * A + B;
    E = C * A + B;

    printf("Total is %.1f\n", D);
    printf("total is %d", E);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Your learning materials are not very good.  Casts should be avoided unless there is no other option.

Comment: M.M, I am using the 'Absolute beginners guide to C Programming', is there a better book than that? Thanks

Comment: [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for some recommendations

Comment: Thank you, I see you are an expert in C , any one in particular you would recommend instead ? Appreciate it

Comment: I don't have a specific recommendation , anything from that thread which has been upvoted should be good

Comment: C doesn't use the term "typecast". `(float)` is an example of a cast operator. It specifies an explicit type conversion. Type conversions may also be done implicitly in many contexts. In fact, *most* conversions should be implicit, and any use of a cast operator should be viewed with suspicion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never need to explicitly typecast to `float` unless you want to force a precise operation between to `int`s, for example

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;
```

`a / b` yields `3` of type `int` (because it's an integer division), while `a / (float)b` yields `3.3333..` of type `float`.

C language specification in addition ensures you that an integer type can be implicitly converted to a float whenever it's necessary to do so (eg. an operation with another float). In addition narrowing can occur if you assign a `float` value to an `int` variable, in that case value is truncated. (§6.3.1.4 of C11)

Answer (score 1):

By convention, C will upcast an arithmetic expression into a `float` if the expression has even one `float` variable.  So the following two expressions would end up being `float`:

```
int A = 3;
float F = 1.0;
float result1 = A * F;  // result is 3.0
float result2 = A / F;  // result is also 3.0
float result3 = A - F;  // result is 2.0
```

In your actual code, you have the following expression:

```
D = C * A + B;
```

In terms of order of operations, we can rewrite the right hand side like this:

```
((C * A) + B);
```

C will evaluate this as follows:

```
((float + int) + int)
((float) + int)
float
```

Comment: This is not very well worded, for example `float = int / int + float` still does integer division